# Распарсить две даты и вычислить диапазон между ними

Tags: php

Задача такова - написать функцию которая парсит полученные даты, и возвращает диапазон между ними. 
Но нюанс в том что иногда дата это просто год (*2015*), а иногда год и месяц (*November 2018*).

Comment: и ваша проблема заключается в.... ?

Comment: @teran в том как написать функцию которая будет возвращать диапазон дат, в не зависимости от того какая дата получена, просто год или год и месяц

Comment: То есть вы хотите написать уже готовую функцию `date_diff()` ?

Comment: @Alpha прочитайте задачу медленно. Узнать диапазон это просто. Но это пользовательская функция, и пользователь может указать дату просто год, а может как год и месяц. И если вы знаете php функция `DateTime::createFromFormat` создает дату если я знаю какой формат даты, а я не знаю какой формат. В этом и проблема!

Comment: Решайте зазачу, за вас её вам решать не будут. Если есть какие-то конкретные вопросы по поводу отдельных частей которые вы не понимаете - вот про них и спрашиваете. А то по вашему стилу вопрошания видно, что вы пришли чтобы за вас здесь сделали ВАШУ работу.

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov да не надо за меня ничего делать, я спрашиваю  может ли есть какая-то функция в php коротая мне может помочь. Или подсказать как написать функция которая создает дату из строки полученную от пользователя, с тем нюансом что может быть два вида даты.

Comment: @DavidAmerov в таком случае можете воспользоваться поиском здесь, либо на англоязычном SO ([ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43873454/identify-date-format-from-a-string-in-php)). В любом случае настолько универсальной функции нет в PHP, и вам нужно будет сначала определить формат даты/даты-и-времени.

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov ясно, понял, спасибо за ответ

Comment: Проверьте is_numeric вашу строку. определите формат. если с месяцем, то добавте вперед `1 ` и используйте `strtotime`, иначе `mktime` и т.п. А что хотите за диапазоны дальше делать  не ясно.

Comment: @David Amerov Напишите примеры типов дат - есть ли с русским языком или только латинские, формат года только в таком виде, может ли меняться последовательность - сначала год, а потом месяц?

Comment: @Denis640Kb два варианта дат, или просто год (2015) или месяц и год (November 2018), месяц всегда впереди и всегда на английском

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если необходимо вывести просто количество месяцев и лет в диапазоне, то можно остановиться на `$result = $interval->m. ' месяцев '.$interval->y. ' лет';`
Если же необходимо вывести массив месяцев, то так (при желании можно и по дням разбить, но в данном контексте в этом нет смысла, так как нигде дата не указывается):
**P.S** Добавил проверку, чтобы даты можно было указывать в любой последовательности.

```php
$dat1 = 'November 2018';
$dat2 = '2016';

function checkdate1($val, $val2){ // Получаем в функции 2 даты
    $dats = [$val,$val2]; // Помещаем в массив
    foreach ($dats as $item) { // Запускаем цикл
        $dat = explode(' ', $item); // Разбиваем дату по пробелу
        if (count($dat) == 1) { // Если количество равно 1, то...
            $item = 'January ' . $item; // Записываем в начале январь, т.к. указан просто год.
        }
        $dd = new DateTime($item); // Преобразуем в datetime
        $dats1[] = $dd; // Помещаем в массив
    }

    if ($dats1[1] < $dats1[0]){ // Если вторая дата меньше первой, то меняем их местами
        $temp = $dats1[0];
        $dats1[0] = $dats1[1];
        $dats1[1] = $temp;
    }

    $interval = $dats1[1]->diff($dats1[0]); // Получаем разницу datetime

    $months = $interval->y * 12 + $interval->m; // получаем месяцы

    if ($months >= 1) { // Если их больше или равно 1, то...
        $period = new DatePeriod($dats1[0], new DateInterval('P1M'), $months); // Получаем период
        $format = 'm.Y'; // устанавливам формат вывода дат.
    } else {
        return 'Указан один и тот же месяц'; // Если месяцев меньше, то выводим сообщение.
    }

    $result = []; // Массив для сохранения результатов
    foreach ($period as $date) { // Запускаем цикл
        $result[] = $date->format($format); // Записываем дату в указанном формате.
    }

    return $result; // Возвращаем результат
}
print_r(checkdate1($dat2, $dat1)); // Запускаем функцию и передаём в неё даты.
```

Comment: Гениально, спасибо